# Как найти наибольший возраст в массиве дат рождений?

Tags: javascript

```
let users = [
    { name: 'Jonny Walker', birthDate: '1995-12-17' },
    { name: 'Andrew', birthDate: '2001-10-29' }
];
```

Comment: что вы не можете вычислить - возраст или наибольший?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const users = [
    { name: 'Jonny Walker', birthDate: '1995-12-17' },
    { name: 'Andrew', birthDate: '2001-10-29' }
];

const birthDate = users.sort((a, b) => a.birthDate.localeCompare(b.birthDate))[0].birthDate;
let maxAge;
if (birthDate) {
    maxAge = new Date().getFullYear() - new Date(birthDate).getFullYear();
}
console.log(maxAge);
```

Comment: прикольно, но как-то боязно сравнивать даты, как строки)

Comment: @Дмытрык в условии задачи именно строки, а не даты. но я не вижу проблемы сделать sort умеющий и дату, и строку